# Throw out rows of same ID that are close in time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe that includes a column with an ID called VIN and a column with a date. If the same VIN has multiple rows with dates that are less than 2 months apart, I would like to throw out the later dates. Here's a minimal example:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'ID': ['ABD','ABD','CDE','CDE','FEK'] }) 
df.head()
```

[image: df.head()]

Here I would like to throw out row 1 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `ID` and get the difference between 2 dates with [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and check whether it is less than 2 months by comparing with [`np.timedelta64(2, 'M')`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime-and-timedelta-arithmetic).  Then filter by `.loc` on the boolean mask of negation of the condition.

```
mask = df.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff() < np.timedelta64(2, 'M')
df_filtered = df.loc[~mask]
```

Result:

```
print(df_filtered)

        Date   ID
0 2015-02-28  ABD
2 2015-04-30  CDE
4 2015-06-30  FEK
```